# NSIS ReadRegStr does not find a registry key which exists

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry, nsis

I'm making a simple NSIS installator on Win 10 and I'm having some issues with a function `ReadRegStr`. `ReadRegStr` returns an empty string and sets a error flag which means the value could not be found. The value definitely exists (it was made by me) and is of a proper type REG_SZ.

The same behavior occurs even with *SOME* other keys:

- HKLM SOFTWARE\FooBar (**not working**)
- HKLM SOFTWARE\Docker Inc.\Docker\1.0 (**not working**)
- HKLM SOFTWARE\Classes/.3gp (**working**)
- HKCU Software\Python\PythonCore\3.6\InstallPath (**working**)

Powershell finds the values without any problems.

```sh
PS C:\Users\Admin\test> Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\FooBar
(default)    : fb
```

Here is a lightweight `nsi` script which I'm using

```sh
OutFile "Installer.exe"
Var FOO_VAR
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
  ReadRegStr $FOO_VAR HKLM "SOFTWARE\FooBar" ""

  ${If} ${Errors}
    MessageBox MB_OK "Value not found"
  ${Else}
    MessageBox MB_OK "FooBar $FOO_VAR"
  ${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

All the keys above have at least read permission for every user/installer.
What else could be causing this?

Comment: 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 64b Pro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

64-bit Windows has [two registry "views"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector) and 32-bit applications see the 32-bit view by default. You can use the `SetRegView` instruction to force a 32-bit NSIS installer to use to the 64-bit view:

```
!include x64.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section
${If} ${RunningX64}
  SetRegView 64
  ReadRegStr ... value on 64-bit systems
  SetRegView LastUsed
${Else}
  ReadRegStr ... value on 32-bit systems
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```